# Delete string from line that matches regex with AWK

Tags: awk

I have file that contains a lot of data like this and I have to delete everything that matches this regex `[-]+\d+(.*)`

Input:

```
zxczxc-6-9hw7w
qweqweqweqweqwe-18-8c5r6
asdasdasasdsad-11-br9ft
```

Output should be:

```
zxczxc
qweqweqweqweqwe
asdasdasasdsad
```

How can I do this with AWK?

Comment: I tried few ways to make correct syntax with sub that can cut this but I can't.

Comment: That regexp means different things to different tools using different options so you should state what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK `awk` doesn't support `\d` so you could use `[0-9]`, your regex is correct only thing you need to put it in correct function of `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/-+[0-9].*/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

You don't need the extra <plus> sign afther `[0-9]` as this is covered by the `.*`

Comment: Hi ,    Didn't knew you can use int like `1` for printing or supressing records. Any link where I can read further about this functionality.

Comment: @DigvijayS, Thank you Digvijay; you could see tag info of awk tag; personally I learnt from SO only :) in link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info you could see books and all fine examples there too. BTW 1 means I am making condition TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default action printing of line will happen.

Comment: I dont't understand this sub syntax. When I do: awk '{sub(/[-]+/[0-9]+/(.*)/)} 1' file I got error. That after '1' is unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Post the **actual** error message, not your interpretation of it. Note that the command you executed is not the command Ravinder posted.

Answer (score 4):

`sed` might be easier...

```
$ sed -E 's/-+[0-9].*//' file
```

note that `.*` covers `+.*`

Comment: Based on the Input/Output sample, simply, `sed 's/-.*//'` does it too.

Comment: Not really if the hyphen is followed by non digit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to delete a *string* that matches a regular expression, then all you need to do is substitute it with an empty string. The most straightforward solution is `sed` which is presented by [karafka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61065026/8344060), the other solution is using `awk` as presented by [RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61062212/8344060).

The overall syntax would look like this:

```
sed -e 's/ere//g' file
awk '{gsub(/ere/,"")}1' file
```

with `ere` the regular expression representation. Note I use `g` and `gsub` here to substitute all *non-overlapping* strings.

Due to the nature of the regular expression in the OP, i.e. it ends with `.*`, the `g` can be dropped. It also allows us to write a different `awk` solution which works with field separators:

```
awk -F '-+[0-9]' '{print $1}' file
```